# Can I transfer programs to my RPi via a USB stick from Windows?

Tags: usb, software-installation

My raspberry pi isn't connected to the internet for now, and I don't have the patience to bridge connections and everything. Can I somehow download some linux programs from online through my windows computer, store it into a USB stick, and copy them into the RPi?

Comment: use LAN cable or WiFi adapter. they 1)work 2)work well. messing with packages is a sure way to a lot of pain and trouble.

Comment: @lenik agreed, nothing worse than downloading a package only to realise theres a dependency thats needed, then that dependency needs a dependency, etc.

Comment: I'll bet bridging in windows is the simpler solution. Using an Ethernet cable to the router would be even easier!

Comment: ^ this was 4 years ago haha...

Answer (score 3):

Well you could setup an emulator on your windows computer and install whatever you want in the emulator and then go to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and copy all .deb files to your usb stick.
and on the raspberry pi you install them with dpkg, but you need the right order...
maybe it works by calling `sudo dpkg -i /mnt/stick/*.deb` multiple times. 
Yeah, dirty... i know :(

qemu (the emulator) tutorials:
http://archive.raspbian.org/qemu/README.txt
http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/

Cant you just plug your LAN cable in the raspberry pi for installing stuff and leave your windows machine offline for that time?

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Arch Linux ARM it's quite simple:

1. Go here http://nl.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv6h/
2. Choose and download package (you can find out in which directory it is [here](http://archlinuxarm.org/packages) and save them to USB
3. Connect USB to you RPi
4. Install packages by `pacman -U <package.tar.xz>`

The reason why you shouldn't do it are dependencies - packages could have some dependencies which you don't have installed. Pacman should tell you about it and you'll need to download them and install first.